# PHP i18n language file to ColdFusion struct converter

Tags: php, coldfusion, internationalization

### The Task

My task was to take a php i18n language file and convert it to a ColdFusion struct. Here is a portion of the input

```
...
"ASK_DELETE"                =>  "<em>D</em>elete", // 'd' is the accesskey identifier
"BACKUP_OF"                 =>  'Backup of',
"PAGE_TITLE"                =>  "Page Title",
...
```

### Current Attempt at converting

The code below **does** work for the php language file that I have been handed. The issue is, the code looks like the beginning of spaghetti code. Some of the things I don't like are

- If one more string pattern comes along, things will crash
- I have a variable called "value"
- Lots of mid string based chopping.

The code looks like the beginning of spaghetti code. What kinds of things should be done about this?

```
    <cffunction name="readPropertiesFile" returnType="Struct" hint="Read a properties file and return a structure">
    <cfargument name="propertiesFile" type="string" required="true" hint="path to properties file">


    <cfscript>
        VAR stProperties = {};
        VAR phpText = "";
        VAR key = "";
        VAR value = "";
        VAR line = "";

       var propertiesFilePath = "#GetDirectoryFromPath(GetBaseTemplatePath())##arguments.propertiesfile#";


       if (NOT FileExists(propertiesFilePath))

        return stProperties;

     </cfscript>




    <!--- read props file --->
    <cffile action="read" file="#propertiesFilePath#" variable="phpText">



    <!--- remove any whitespace at top and tail --->
    <cfset phpText = trim(phpText)>

    <!--- remove comments and blank lines --->
    <cfset phpText = ReReplace(phpText,"(?m)\##.*?$", "","all")>
    <cfset phpText = ReReplace(phpText,"[#Chr(10)#]{2,}", "#Chr(10)#","all")>
    <cfset phpText = ReplaceList(phpText, '",', '"')>


    <!--- loop over each line, ignore comments (#...) and insert keys/values into return struct --->
    <cfloop list="#phpText#" index="line" delimiters="#CHR(10)#">
    <cfscript>

    line = trim(line);
    splitAt = Find("=>", line);
    CommentAt = Find("//", line);

    if (splitAt != 0)   {

        key =  replacelist(trim(Left(line, splitAt - 1)), '"', "");

        if (CommentAt == 0)
    value = replacelist(trim(Mid(line, splitAt + 2, 1000)), '"', '');
        else
            value = replacelist(trim(Mid(line, splitAt + 2, CommentAt - (splitAt + 2))), '"', '');

        //  Remove trailing , 
    if (right(value, 1) == ",")
            value = mid(value, 1, len(value) - 1);


    if (right(value, 1) == "'")
        value = mid(value, 1, len(value) - 1);


    if (left(value, 1) == "'")
        value = mid(value, 2, 1000);



        stProperties[key] = value;
        } // end if
    </cfscript>
</cfloop>

<cfreturn stProperties>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would be my approach. You can of course make this more resilient or add error trapping to catch inconsistent file parsing. I'm assuming there won't be quotes in the key values.

```
<!--- Going on the Assumption there isn't commas or quotations inside the values of the key --->
<cfsavecontent variable="fileData">

"ASK_DELETE"                =>  "<em>D</em>elete", // 'd' is the accesskey identifier
"BACKUP_OF"                 =>  'Backup of',

"PAGE_TITLE"                =>  "Page Title"

</cfsavecontent>

<cfset i18n = structNew()>
<!--- Remove // Comments --->
<cfset fileData = REReplace(fileData,"//.*?\n","","ALL")>
<!--- Simplify Delimiter --->
<cfset fileData = Replace(fileData,"=>","|","ALL")>

<cfloop list="#fileData#" delimiters="," index="thisEntry">
    <!--- Strip Quotes and Pull Entries --->
    <cfset key = REReplace(ListFirst(thisEntry,"|"),"[""']","","ALL")>
    <cfset value = REReplace(ListLast(thisEntry,"|"),"[""']","","ALL")>
    <cfset structInsert(i18n,trim(key),trim(value))>
</cfloop>

<cfdump var="#i18n#">
```

Comment: I would strongly suggest that you not use a pipe `|` as the replacement delimiter and instead use the splat character `chr(7)`. when replacing delimiter its better to avoid ANY ascii characters that  common.

Comment: I recommend you use ResourceBundle.cfc by Paul Hasting to handle this. Your delimiter would be an "=", which no spaces to the left or right of it. His code reads in the resource bundle file and converts it to a struct when the application loads. http://code.google.com/p/cfi18n/source/browse/#svn%2Ftrunk

Comment: There are commas in the original file

Comment: In the value of keys? If so, then just have to modify the regex expression to exclude commas inside of quotes or massage it to make it easier. And of course you can improve and use whatever safe delimiters you feel are best.

Answer (score 0):

it's 10 years too late, but why not just replace ' =>  ' with a colon and surround with curly brace and treat as json?

```
"ASK_DELETE"                =>  "<em>D</em>elete", // 'd' is the accesskey identifier
"BACKUP_OF"                 =>  'Backup of',
"PAGE_TITLE"                =>  "Page Title"
```

to

```
{
"ASK_DELETE"                :  "<em>D</em>elete", // 'd' is the accesskey identifier
"BACKUP_OF"                 :  'Backup of',
"PAGE_TITLE"                :  "Page Title"
}
```

for others finding this after 2023 from searching.